# is it possible to Only pull related users through foreign key relationship, once in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

Hi im fairly new to the amazing world of django!

Basically im working on a project that requires me to create a fairly unique email notifications system that users can use to refine the updates they recieve via email when new blog posts are made on the site.

I think im gonna have a ton of questions about this project as its proving to be a really steep learning curve so i thought id try it all myself first then run here for help when i get stuck!

Basically users can opt in to recieve updates for the following
ALl new blog posts
Or select from a check box form thier favourite authors
etc

The first thing i have run into is pulling the users out from the database.  I know how to get all the user details for each blog but this obviously gives me back duplicate user details for users that have published more than one blog.  so i need a way to only get the user info for those users who have posted a blog and only get thier details once.

MODEL

```
class Blog(models.Model):

     user = models.ForeignKey(User, help_text = "The User posting this blog entry")
     news = models.ForeignKey(News, unique = True, blank = True, null = True, help_text = "Is this Blog entry related to a news posts IE and Expert Analysis")
     title = models.CharField(max_length = 120, help_text = "The Title of this blog entry")
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 150, help_text = "This Field is auto-populated by the title field, its simply used for the CMS urls")
     info = models.TextField()
     categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
     sectors = models.ManyToManyField(Sectors)
     tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
     published = models.DateTimeField()
     status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'd')

     class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = "Blog entries"
         verbose_name = "Blog"
         ordering = ['-published']

     def __unicode__ (self):
         return self.title
```

As you can i see i am using django's user model as a foreign key to store the authors details. Should i scrap this approach and set up a seperate model for the blog authors or can what i am trying to do be achieved using the built in User model.

So to conclude what i am aiming for is be able to get a list of all the users that have posted a blog post but only grab their details once thus giving me a list of names and ids so that i can create a form using check boxes that the user can tick to opt in to receive updates!

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a single query for users that have at least one blog entry:

```
User.objects.exclude(blog=None)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response, this has worked a treat! A bit embarrassed i didn't figure it out! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Daniel's solution works since there is no blog field in the User model related to your Blog model (that I'm aware of). But if it works, that's great.

If you find you're still having a problem with it, then maybe this will help. I have two options.
First, if all you need are the ids and names then this may work.

```
users = Blog.objects.all().order_by('user__username').values('user__id', 
        'user__username').distinct()
```

Second, if you want the actual User objects, then this might be what you're after.

```
userids = Blog.objects.all().values_list('user__id', flat=True)
users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=userids).order_by('username')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer this was along the lines of what i was trying so its great to know where i was going wrong.